APUE, Why MAXSLEEP defined value, divided by 2
In APUE, in figure 16-11, the code is as follows:
#include "apue.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define MAXSLEEP 128

int connect_retry(int domain, int type, int protocol, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t alen) {
   int numsec, fd;
   /* Try to connect with exponential backoff. */
   
   for (numsec = 1; numsec <= MAXSLEEP; numsec <<= 1) {
      if ((fd = socket(domain, type, protocol)) < 0)
         return(-1);
      if (connect(fd, addr, alen) == 0) {
      /* Connection accepted. */
         return(fd);
      }
      close(fd);

      /* Delay before trying again.*/       
      if (numsec <= MAXSLEEP/2)      -- question line
         sleep(numsec);
   }
   return(-1);

}
My question is: Why MAXSLEEP is define as 128 and It's division by 2 is evaluated, and not defined 64 without any division?

The intention of the code is that on failure, there's a sleep of 1 second, then 2 seconds, then 4 seconds and so on (so-called "exponential backoff"). That's achieved in the for loop, with numsec <<= 1 being a way of writing numsec*=2. On the final iteration there should be no sleep on failure, because there's going to be no more retries. On the final iteration, numsec * 2 will be larger than MAXSLEEP, which is tested via numsec <= MAXSLEEP/2.
My guess for this code is that this if condition was added later and when the code was originally written, MAXSLEEP was indeed the maximum sleep. Later, it was noticed that the code unnecessarily sleeps for 128 seconds on failure, and the condition added without updating the variable name to be descriptive.
